# Dissecting Africa

Tags: dissection, word-search, polyomino, anagram

A straightforward puzzle for the patient. There are no *tricks* or *decryptions* needed. The task is 'simple' albeit potentially challenging (and maybe time-consuming).

> ## The goal
>
> Dissect the Africa-grid below into **54 pieces** of different shape and size.
>   - Each piece consists of fully connected squares, i.e. is a [polyomino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino).
>   - The letters on each piece are [anagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anagram). 
>   - All anagrams belong to the same group of words, defining the dissection property.
>   - The anagrams may contain one or more 'white spaces'.
>   - The English language is used.
>   If you dissect it correctly, you may be able to spot a rather well-known word in an African native language. (*Googling the word gives 125,000,000+ results*)

---

[image: DissectThisInto54Pieces]

Comment: Did you make this?

Comment: @kaine Sure, why? (If you find a mistake or have ideas for improvement, let me know.)

Comment: Only because if it works and you did im impressed

Comment: @kaine BmyGuest's puzzles always seem to be **really** impressive.

Comment: I guess it would be poor taste to make an educated guess at the "final" word without finding any polyominos. It does show "About 125,000,000 results" when I Google it, though ;)

Comment: yeah... the final word hint gave it away for me. it's super easy to guess the answer with 0 work

Comment: @Geobits: that (easy to guess) word is not the solution, but the verification anchor to help limit the parameter space and put back some faith into your solution. You still have to *find* it though. The *dissection* is the solution.

Comment: @BmyGuest Oh I know. I wasn't sure if you wanted it blurted out in the comments or not. If I thought it was the answer I'd have answered with it (and been downvoted I'm sure).

Comment: This was fun to do!

Comment: @GoldenDragon Thanks! Solved in less than 24hrs. I have to make things trickier ;c)

Comment: Where is Madagascar?

Comment: @VictorStafusa Too small (too few squares) to put it appropriately on the map, so I restricted to mainland (continental) mass only. Basically I took an Africa map image and scaled it down to get to ~pixels I needed (=letters) and then edited to get the best representation. Madagascar didn't look good at all.

Comment: It kinda infuriates me (not at you, just in general) that the countries aren't in their respective locations on the actual map of Africa. I was like, "why is Zimbabwe all the way to the west side?"

Comment: @JoeZ. ;c) I was actually thinking of producing something more "correct" first, but soon thought of it as being too easy (to solve) and to tricky (to built). Plus: the smallest places have the largest names...

Comment: Small country, big ego, I guess.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Got the dissection part done.  No idea about the native African word, though.

> The 54 pieces are the various [nations of Africa](https://www.countries-ofthe-world.com/countries-of-africa.html)
>  [image: Africa]

Comment: I see a `B` in there (in pink), and maybe an `L`.

Comment: Morocco, Mauritius, Sao Tome and Principe, Libya, Cote d'Ivorie, Mauritania, Madagascar, Comoros, Cabo Verde... I'm missing a country/letter :(

Comment: If you colour your solution differently, you will see. I'm going to post in a sec...

Comment: @Geobits: You miss it, because the dissection is not 100% like mine. Benin/Niger could be dissected differently. That's why you miss the T in this solution.

Comment: Ah, so Benin and Chad for the last? I figured it was something like that, was looking for ambiguities.

Comment: @Geobits Yes, see below.

Comment: You have an extra I in NAMIBIA which should be in GUINEA.

Answer (score 8):

**[Golden Dragon](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/239/golden-dragon)** has solved it, but for the record, this is as intended:

> [image: Solution]

---

> [image: UBUNTU]

Comment: Another fantastic puzzle!

Comment: I think it's very difficult to see the Ubuntu, although it can be guessed when you say "a well-known word in African native language", haha