# Rebuilding the Rio 2016 Olympics logo

Tags: visual, tiling, word-search, sports

This puzzle belongs to the puzzle series: [hyper-modern art](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=hyper-modern%20is%3Aquestion)
<sub>It is also an entry to the [13th fortnightly challenge](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5206/fortnightly-topic-challenge-13-sports-for-the-rio-olympics/5207#5207)</sub>

---

You two friends are still venturing through the endless halls of the gallery of hyper-modern art.

"Oh, look, this time there is a quite modern piece featuring an on-going event!"

*"Really? I don't quite get it. I bet, all these letters are supposed to spell something out, right? But without my HUD I'm not seeing it. What is it?"*

"You're quite right, but not exactly. The piece is called **Rio 2016**, because it resembles the logo of the 2016 Olympics."

*"It does? I'm not seeing it, what's the trick?"*

"Take a look through my HUD. See how the pieces re-arrange themselves now?"

*"Ah, yes. Now I can see it. But why all these letters?"*

"Let me show you", he turns another knob on the HUD, "see how these groups now form words? And when you read them..."

*"Ah, yes, quite clever. But could one do that without the HUD, I wonder...."*

---

[image: Puzzle pieces]

---

Your task in this puzzle is straight forward and simple:

> Assemble the puzzle pieces below into an arrangement which best matches the *shape* of the Rio 2016 logo.

<sub>So, the solution is picture of the rearranged puzzle tiles in the (rough) shape of the Rio 2016 logo.</sub>

Just in case you don't know what the Rio 2016 logo looks like, here it is:
[image: Rio2016]

### But here's the catch:

> When all pieces are put together, it must be possible to split the final shape into *different* connected pieces (consisting of multiple squares which are all connected via common edges, not corners) such that each of these pieces contains letters which can be re-arranged into one of the Olympic sports of the game. All letters must be used that way. (Similar to this [puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10016/dissecting-africa?s=1%7C2.1281).)

Here is an example:
[image: Example]

A few clarifications:

- Puzzle pieces may be rotated
- The orientation of the letters in the square are just to obscure tile orientation
- For puzzle-building reason, the list of Olympic sports has been slightly modified (and not all sports are used), so if you prefer the list, it is:

  > `Archery Athletics Badminton Basketball Boxing Canoe Cycling Diving Fencing Football Golf Gymnastics Handball Hockey Judo Rowing Rugby Sailing Shooting Swimming Taekwondo Trampoline Triathlon Volleyball Weightlifting Wrestling Pentathlon`
- To find the approximated shape you want to cover, you will need to resize the logo image such that the number of "used" tiles matches. Or, if you want to make your life more simple, use the following image: (spoiler!)

  > [image]

Comment: This puzzle is not for the weak-hearted, and I think it involves quite a bit of work! Initially, I've left out the letter-arrangement forming the logo (there are 210 letters), but in case nobody gets it, I may provide that shape as a hint at later time.

Comment: I'm going to add a 50 bounty on this in two days, even if some-one has already got it. This is certainly deserved of one!

Comment: Having said that, that doesn't mean I'm not going to have a crack at it myself. Think I'll bring out trusty pen and paper here.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Pen, Paper and maybe scissors as well? ;c)

Comment: just wondering if you have an answer to this?

Comment: -1 no water polo (jk, +1'd)

Comment: @ev3commander I had to drop two-component names and *Polo* certainly isn't valid ;c)

Comment: @beastlygerbil yes, a solution does exist and i know it.

Comment: Hm, I feel like "rough shape of the Olympics 2016 logo" leaves too much of a search space. :/

Comment: [If anyone needs it, here's an excel file with the grid tiles.](http://ev3commander.github.io/puzzlegrid.xlsx)

Comment: @Deusovi Maybe you're right. I've uploaded the "restricted" shape now. One would get to it my doing a bit of maths (210 tiles) and image-resizing/thresholding, but maybe it was too much for a single puzzle, and I don't want to frustrate anybody...

Comment: @BmyGuest: The issue was that slight movement to the left or right may exclude some squares and include some new ones such that it still looks roughly like the logo, but has a different arrangement of squares.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> [image: Solution]
>
>  It was way easier with the shape known. I started with the *rugby* part. Then added *fencing*, *archery*, *badminton* and *cycling* on the left. I had the most of the center ready before the shape was added. On the right side the top of *basketball* was the best match. The bottom right part was the hardest because of the unusual placement of *weightlifting*. The rest was simply placing the remaining parts from right to left.

Comment: This looks correct - once Ive got confirmation for @BmyGuest then you'll get the bounty!

Comment: Well done. I knew it would be much easier with the shape provided, but it seemed nobody could crack it without. I hope it wasn't too easy that way though...

Comment: @BmyGuest  Thanks and it wasn't too easy, the big areas (left and bottom right) were still challenging.

Comment: And the bounty goes to you! Well done! I couldn't get this, even with the shape provided

Answer (score 7):

#### Starting Point

---

Here is the frequency of the letters.

[image: Frequency]

There are 210 Tiles which must be fitted into the shape.

Noticeable in the table is that there is only 1 J and 1 X.

This means that the tile with the J and X in it must be part of Judo and Boxing.

[image: Tile]

This tile then seems the key tile to begin with.

Comment: Interesting starting approach. I hope the frequency analysis holds true for both the "tiles" and the keyword-list? (If not, I would have messed up, so it really should ;c))

Comment: @BmyGuest It should, because I just copied that list into a letter frequency counter :P

Comment: Why can't we use the tile that kinda looks like a music note and has `INNHTDU` on it for judo?

Comment: @DooplissForce, you can but not for the u and the d only one of them, because the tile can't be rotated into a position where the two letters fit into the spaces highlighted in red

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil [What about this?](http://i.imgur.com/xEkp7vL.png)

Comment: @DooplissForce, that is correct. I've overlooked the fact that the tiles don't have to touch in order (which I automatically assumed)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Ah, gotcha, no problem :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the bounty. Note that I've uploaded the shape-image, as nobody seems to have worked in that direction so far.